# Convert Text To Varchar

Tags: postgresql

In `Postgresql` how do you convert a text field to a varchar?  I have tried both of the below, but neither convert my text field to varchar.

```
Cast(Iamtextfield As Varchar)
Char(Iamtextfield)
```

Comment: What for? Aren't they the same internally?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

text is just another term for unlimited varchar in PostgreSQL.

But if you want to make sure the type is set correctly in the return output, simply:

```
 iamtextfield::varchar
```

Or if it is case sensitive

```
 "Iamtextfield"::varchar
```

If you want to truncate you can do something like:

```
 iamtextfield::varchar(5)
```

Answer (score 8):

Cast in postgress, text to varchar example:

```
select (select 'example text'::text)::varchar
```