# VBA Unspecified Error When Querying PostgreSQL View

Tags: vba, postgresql

I am querying a PostgreSQL view in VBA:

```
Sub GetData()
Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
     With cn
        .ConnectionString = "Driver={PostgreSQL ANSI(x64)};Database=a;Server=b;Uid=c;Pwd=d;Port=5432;sslmode=require;"
        .Open

    End With

    SqlString = "SELECT * FROM myView;"
    rs.Open SqlString, cn
...
End Sub
```

The query `SELECT * FROM myview;` executes as expected from within pgAdmin. Within VBA, it throws an Unspecified Error. I have used the same VBA code with other simple SQL queries against the same database and it's worked properly.

The view should return 8 columns. If I list those 8 columns in my query in VBA (instead of SELECT *...), the same Unspecified Error is returned.

However, if I leave off one specific column (accountcode, which is text), and instead just return the other 7, it executes properly.

What could be the issue with this one column that's causing it to work properly in pgAdmin but not in VBA?

Thank you.

Comment: Does the view include other columns from the same underlying table as accountcode? Can you query that table, including the column accountcode, using this subprogram?

Comment: The columns are all from the same table. I am able to query the underlying table in VBA, and can return any columns except accountcode.

Comment: Might there be column-level security restrictions on accountcode? If it's type TEXT, perhaps some of the values are larger than ADO can handle in this way? Are there any other TEXT columns? (And by the way, why are you using a view if the columns are all from the same table?)

Comment: There aren't any column level restrictions. The longest value in it is 4 characters. It doesn't need to be a view but was initially set up this way so I decided to stick with it.

Comment: If the widest value is 4 characters, what happens if you alter the table so the type of that column is VARCHAR(4) rather than TEXT (or if there might be wider values in the future, some wider VARCHAR)?

Comment: I altered the column to a varchar(10) and am encountering the same error.

Comment: This is my last Hail Mary: Is there any possibility that any of the values it's trying to return includes unusual or non-printable characters?

Comment: I'm not sure - I changed the driver I was using to Unicode and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

Seems the problem is the (ODBC? see if it has configuration options that would be useful for this) driver making wrong assumptions about handling the `TEXT` data type.

Not familiar with [postgresql](/questions/tagged/postgresql) in any way, but according to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38918110/1188513) about casting from `TEXT` to `VARCHAR`, consider explicitly listing each column you're selecting from the view (`SELECT *` is bad practice anyway), and then you can do something like this:

```
Dim sql As String
sql = "SELECT Field1, Field2, ThatTextField::varchar FROM myView;"
```

Also consider moving the connection and query code over to a class module, where your ADODB connection can be declared as a module-level `WithEvents` variable; then you can handle ADODB connection events like `WillConnect`, `WillExecute`, and `InfoMessage`, which can give you more meaningful error messages.